# Hackerrank distribute chocolates equally

Tags: java, algorithm

I am going through this hackerrank problem statement - [Equals](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/equal/problem)

> Christy is interning at HackerRank. One day she has to distribute some
>   chocolates to her colleagues. She is biased towards her friends and
>   plans to give them more than the others. One of the program managers
>   hears of this and tells her to make sure everyone gets the same
>   number.
>
> To make things difficult, she must equalize the number of chocolates
>   in a series of operations. For each operation, she can give 1, 2, or 5
>   chocolates to all but one colleague. Everyone who gets chocolate in a
>   round receives the same number of pieces.
>
> For example, assume the starting distribution is [1,1,5] . She can give  bars
>   to the first two and the distribution will be [3,3,5]. On the next round, she
>   gives the same two 2 bars each, and everyone has the same number: [5,5,5].
>
> Given a starting distribution, calculate the minimum number of
>   operations needed so that every colleague has the same number of
>   chocolates.

Now I found out this code is working fine in hackerrank:

```
static int equal(int[] arr) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        min = Math.min(min, arr[i]);
    }
    int bestResult = Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2;
    for (int borderline = min; borderline >= 0; borderline--) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            result += (arr[i] - borderline) / 5;
            result += (arr[i] - borderline) % 5 / 2;
            result += (arr[i] - borderline) % 5 % 2 / 1;
        }
        bestResult = Math.min(bestResult, result);
    }
    return bestResult;
}
```

In above code, first we are trying to get the minimum element from array, then I am not able to understand how the `bestResult` is calculated using nested loops. I tried to debug this code in my eclipse but I am not able to understand how this logic is solving the problem statement.

**Can you please help me in understanding this program.**

Also I see only a single test case is failing, what is the reason for it.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger, yes, but my actual question was more on understanding this code. I just highlighted it now.

Comment: [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  Asking us to assimilate the problem and reverse-engineer the entire solution, is out of scope.  Trace the execution.  Explain to us how it addresses the solution.  Detail where you got blocked.  *That* is in scope.

Comment: @Prune, I tried to debug this code several times in my eclipse IDE, but I was not able to understand how the logic is solving the problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm becomes simpler if we understand that

> Giving everyone else except one person == reducing for one person and
>   not everyone else.

This means that, we know what the final values would look like. A list of n numbers with all being `min` value. We can just count how many steps it takes each number to get to minimum. In the example `[1,1,5]`, 5 takes 2 steps to get to 1 and now all are equal. 
That's the innerloop you are seeing above (when `borderline` is `min`). This greedily reduces each number to the minimum in fastest way. Take as many 5s as possible and then 2s and finally 1.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result += (arr[i] - borderline) / 5;            // no. of 5s
        result += (arr[i] - borderline) % 5 / 2;        // from the remainder, no. of 2s
        result += (arr[i] - borderline) % 5 % 2 / 1;    // from the above remainder, no of 1s
    }
```

However, this doesn't solve for all cases. We are assuming that goal is to reach 'minimum' value in the given list, but sometimes it may take less number of steps to reach a different number other than minimum. This value where all values should converge is `borderline` variable in your pasted code.

Let's take `[1,5,5]`. If we apply the same logic as making all the elements as 1s, then we will get 4 steps. But, making them all 0s, will take only 3 steps.

To determine which is the best baseline whether all the reductions should be counted to `min` variable or some other number less than `min`,
the outerloop is checking for all the numbers between `0` to `min` (which gives the best borderline) that gives minimum steps.

Hope this explanation clarifies the code in the question.

Note:
For some more optimization, that loop doesn't require to check from `0` to `min`. If the baseline is venturing far from `min`, it just requires extra steps to get there from `min` itself and won't give the minimum steps and just costs computation times.

It's enough to check for `min`, `min-1` and `min-2` borderlines alone. As going for more will result in extra step. So the outerloop can look like

```
 for (int borderline = min; borderline >= min-2; borderline--)
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please give explanation on inner loop more on line by line `result += (arr[i] - borderline) / 5;
        result += (arr[i] - borderline) % 5 / 2;
        result += (arr[i] - borderline) % 5 % 2 / 1;` why we are dividing by 5, 2, 1, how this division helps to get a solution and also which operator to use when `/` and `%`

Comment: check my edit. It's a fancy looking thing to just reduce a number to a minimum by greedily removing 5s, 2s and 1s

Answer (score 0):

```
result += (arr[i] - borderline) / 5; result += (arr[i] - borderline) % 5 / 2; result += (arr[i] - borderline) % 5 % 2 / 1;
```

Here:

- `(arr[i] - borderline) / 5` gives how many times 5 can be subtracted
- `(arr[i] - borderline) % 5` gives what is left
- `/2` gives how many 2 can be subtracted
- `(arr[i] - borderline) % 5 % 2` gives what is left
- `/1` gives how many times 1 can be subtracted

For more explanation, you can see [this link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/equal/forum/comments/227783)

Comment: The link you provided requires me to either login or create an account. Doesn't seem appropriate to force me to join hackerrank just to see your link.

Comment: The login can be canceled. There is a cross at the top right when you open the link.